# Prepend text to a different file from within Vim

Tags: bash, sed, vim, txt

I am trying to *prepend* text from within Vim to another file. Specifically the current line, but a visual selection would be nice as well. Eventually I would like to map it to something like `<leader>i`.

In bash I can use the following sed command to achieve this:

```
sed -i '1i some new text' myfile.md
```

So I tried this from within vim:

```
:execute "!sed -i '1i" .getline('.') "' myfile.md"
```

This works but when there is an `!` in the currentline: `shell returned 2`.

Then I found out about shellescape, and I got the following command to work. Now it seems like I'm doing something wrong escaping characters as this will add single quotes around the string.

```
:execute "!sed -i \"1i " . shellescape(getline('.'), 1) . "\" myfile.m
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way?

Comment: Why use `sed` from `vim`? You're in Vim, why not use its power? Open the file in a buffer, go to the 1st line (in case opening a file restores different position), prepend the current line before the 1st, save, delete the buffer.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this quickly and repeatedly, to the same file. Preferably by mapping it to a key combo as I mentioned

Comment: I don't see how calling `sed` from Vim would be quicker then using the very Vim. Precise timings should be benchmarked, of course. Write a function, call it from any mapping a hundred of times.

Comment: I'm not familiar with functions in vim but thanks for the tip, I will look into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function! PrependLine()
    " Save the current file to avoid problems with switching buffers
    update
    " Copy the current line to the default register
    yank
    " Open a new buffer or switch to exiting one
    edit myfile.md
    " Paste content of the default register before the 1st line
    1put!
    " Save the file
    update
    " Return to the previous file
    edit #
endfunction

map <leader>i :call PrependLine()<CR>
```

The only problem is — the filename is fixed. Vim macros don't have parameters. Functions do have.

Comment: I'd recommend to get in the habit of using `:nnoremap` by default. And `:tabedit` might enable you to open the second file without having to `:update` first.

Comment: @Friedrich I run `vim` in `rxvt` terminals, never use tabs, never use windows, seldom use splits. I usually open 1 or max 2 files and switch between them using `CTRL-^`. For me `vim` is a programmable text editor, not an IDE; I start `vim`, edit a file, save and exit. Instead of mandate `:update` I use `:set hidden`. :-)

Comment: Moving the comments on the line above the commands would help with legibility.

Comment: @romainl Done, tnx!

Answer (score 2):

To suggest an alternative that makes use of Vim's buffer functions, you could tweak the example given in [`:help bufadd()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#bufadd%28%29) just a little bit. I took the liberty of borrowing the function name from [phd's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78156004/796259).

I'd prefer to have the destination file name as an argument to the function but that's largely up to personal taste.

```
function PrependLine(filename) abort
    let dstbuf = bufadd(a:filename)
    call bufload(dstbuf)
    call appendbufline(dstbuf, 0, getline('.'))
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>i <Cmd>call PrependLine('myfile.md')<CR>
```

Note that this will not write a file to disc right now but keep it open as an unlisted buffer. It will be written only when you explicitly do so, e.g. through `:wall`. This function also avoids the side effect of writing the current buffer.